# java.io.IOException: if running the application a second Time

Tags: java, java-io, ioexception, http-status-code-400

first of all sorry for my bad English, but i'm from Germany. Nevertheless i hope you understand what's my problem here.
I'm working on an Webclient, which should download an XML-File from the SAP C4C Odata Service. Everything is working great if i'm starting the application and run the download for the first time. But if the first run is finished and i am trying to download the next file the application is throwing the following Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: --
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
at com.model.Model.createTemp(Model.java:164)
at com.model.Model.checkFilter(Model.java:122)
at com.model.Model$1.actionPerformed(Model.java:50)
```

I have searched for the problem the last days but never found the solution.
Maybe you Guys are seeing something what i've failed to see.

That's my code, where i am downloading the String from the URL.

```
public void createTemp(String odata) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {

    File export = new File("temp");

    if (!export.exists()) {
        export.mkdir();
    }

    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {          
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass.toCharArray());
        }
    });

    out = new Scanner(new URL(odata).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();


    OutputStreamWriter xmlout = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("temp\\tempout.xml"), "UTF-8");
    xmlout.write(out);
    xmlout.close();

    File xml = new File("temp\\tempout.xml");

    writeCSV(xml);

}
```

Thanks to all of you in Advance!

Comment: 400 means bad request, so it depends on what data you are sending to what URL - you might have to be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: try using xmlout.flush() before xmlout.close()

Comment: @cssGEEK Why? [`close()` calls `flush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close()).

Comment: i am trying to download the next file -> doesn that mean your URL / `odata` is maybe different for that file? Can you give contents of odata?

Comment: have you tried to download in another order ?, or by hand, if it's possible ? just to see if it's not a problem at the server ?

Comment: This is 2015; why do you still use `File`?

Comment: My URL is changing with each URL-Call.
https://<C4C_Tenant>/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codata/AccountCollection
It's a normal C4C-Odata URL. If I'm accessing it with a Browser it's always working.

And I'm using File because i've learned it that way. Never used something other. The Error is happening at the Scanner-Line.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm an idiot and have found my mistake. I've ever searched in my InputStream if i've forgot to close something. But my Code has appended the URL everytime, so that he has used the URL from the last call and added the Parts for the new Call to it.